# Pull-back of a divisor via composition with a rational map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y,Z$ be smooth projective varieties (say, over $\mathbb{C}$.) Let $f:X\to Y$ and $h:X\to Z$ be surjective morphisms and let $g:Y\dashrightarrow Z$ be a surjective rational map (not just dominant) such that $h=g\circ f$ as rational maps. Let $D$ be an effective divisor on $Z$ and note that $g^*D$ is defined. Is it true that $h^*D\le f^*g^*D$ as divisors on $X$?

To be fair, the case I need is $Z=\mathbb{P}^1$ and when $f$ is a birational morphism, but I am curious about the general case too.

Comment: If $g$ is not a morphism, then it has a point of indeterminacy, say $y \in Y$. If $f$ is surjective, then $g \circ f$ has a point of indeterminacy at any point in $f^{-1}(y)$, i.e. $h$ is not a morphism. What am I missing?

Comment: @pinaki Perhaps this example will clarify the situation: Take $Y=\mathbb{P}^2$, a point $p\in \mathbb{P}^2$, let $f:X\to Y$ be the blow-up of $Y$ at $p$, choose $Z=\mathbb{P}^1$, and let $g:Y\to Z$ be the projection from $p$. Now let $D$ be a point in $Z=\mathbb{P}^1$. Then $g^*D=L$ is a line through $p$. Let $E$ be the exceptional divisor of $f$ and let $H$ be the strict transform of $L$. Then $h^*D=H$ while $f^*g^*D=H+E$.